# Insert list or tuple into table without iteration into postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, tld

I am new to python. What I am trying to achieve is to insert values from my list/tuple into my redshift table without iteration.I have around 1 million rows and 1 column. 
Below is the code I am using to create my list/tuple.

```
cursor1.execute("select domain from url limit 5;")
for record, in cursor1:
    ext = tldextract.extract(record)
    mylist.append(ext.domain + '.' + ext.suffix)

mytuple = tuple(mylist)
```

I am not sure what is best to use, tuple or list. output of `print(mylist)` and `print(mytuple)` are as follows.

> List output 
>   ['friv.com', 'steep.tv', 'wordpress.com', 'fineartblogger.net',
>   'v56.org'] 
> Tuple Output
> ('friv.com', 'steep.tv', 'wordpress.com',
>   'fineartblogger.net', 'v56.org')

Now, below is the code I am using to insert the values into my redshift table but I am getting an error:

```
cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO sample(domain) VALUES (%s)", mylist) or
cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO sample(domain) VALUES (%s)", mytuple)
```

> Error - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Any help is appreciated. If any other detail is required please let me know, I will edit my question.

**UPDATE 1:** 
Tried using below code and getting different error.

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s)", x) for x in mylist)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_str)
```

> ERROR - INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. For some reason `cur.mogrify` was not giving me proper sql string for insert. Created my own SQl string and it works alot faster than `cur.executeall()`

```
list_size = len(mylist)

for len in range(0,list_size):
    if ( len != list_size-1 ):
        sql = sql + ' ('+ "'"+  mylist[len] + "'"+ ') ,'
    else:
        sql = sql + '('+ "'"+  mylist[len] + "'"+ ')'

cursor1.execute("INSERT into sample(domain) values " + sql)
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Fast Execution helpers](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers):

```
mylist=[('t1',), ('t2',)] 
execute_values(cursor2, "INSERT INTO sample(domain) %s", mylist, page_size=100)
```

what this does is it replaces the %s with 100 VALUES. I'm not sure how high you can set page_size, but that should be far more performant.